# Dependency injection special case

Tags: angularjs

Have a look at the following:

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('Gallery',Gallery);
Gallery.$inject=['GalleryService'];
function Gallery(GalleryService){...}

angular.module('myapp',[]).service('GalleryService',GalleryService);
GalleryService.$inject=['$http'];
function GalleryService($http){...};
```

Could someone explain to me **why the second block needs [ ]** inside angular.module? In case I omit it I am getting Exception Error...

Comment: Omitting the second argument creates a reference to a module and including it creates a new module. Do you have `.module('myapp',[])` anywhere else in your project?

Comment: you have to declare a module  once, and that requires second argument ... without second argument it is a getter and if module doesn't exist will throw error. Read the docs for `module`

Answer (score 1):

```
angular.module('myapp', []) registers the module 
angular.module('myapp') references an already created module called 'myapp'
```

You could structure your code like so for a more clear approach:

```
//Register module
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', []);

//Add controllers, service to already created module
myapp.controller(...);
myapp.service(...);
```

The second parameter (the empty array) is for other modules you would like to use and is required when instantiating a new module.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module

Comment: Okay, good answers. However, why I am getting Exception error when I add [ ] into the first block? In other words if I do this to both of the above blocks the code does not work...